# Flexible Android advertisement provider out there?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, ads

I was busy the whole day integrating various ad-providers into my Android application.

I have two specific problems:

I am developing a browser app and, all those ad-providers I tried (f.e. AdMob, Mobiclix, AdWhirl) require their own Activity in my applications manifest. This does not work with my application because It runs in front of the lock screen and requires the FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED being set.

Second problem is, that the ad providers fire a ACTION_VIEW intent to load websites in users browser.
But my app is already the browser app, and I do not want to use the default browser for browsing, instead of my own.

Does anyone know an ad provider, where you can handle the clicks by yourself and do not need to use their custom activities?

Maybe I can also use normal web ad providers, and use a WebView to display the ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually most ad providers don't need an activity to work.
You can use Admob (Download the latest SDK) both through the AdManager activity or through adding an AdView which is their custom view, with no need for an extra activity.

Regarding your other problem, The basic banner ads are usually a closed product where you don't have much flexibility regarding the way they fire the action.
You can, however, receive these events as a browser (i believe).

What I do for apps that can't use banner ads is use sign up ads which works great for me...
Try adleads.pontiflex.com - it actually pays much more than the usual banner ads. If you decide using them I would appreciate if you state me as the referrer (IncrediApp).

Comment: Yes, I can display the banner with AdMob in an AdView, but it requires an activity when CLICKING the ad. Yes I receive those intents, except when the user did choose another browser to handle those. Thanks for your suggestion, will take a look.